# Combining the index ID and values from txt file (java)

Tags: java, arrays, redirect

I'm making a java program that (by cmd redirection) reads standard input from a txtfile that has a format like this:

```
0 Groningen    Leek
1 Drenthe      Emmen
2 Flevoland    Almere
```

this index goes on till ID 518, and by then each ID has its two coordinates, like this:

```
0 6.665039 53.181004
0 6.66608 53.180733
0 6.666431 53.180642
0 6.666313 53.180329
1 6.814185 53.140736
1 6.813501 53.140584
1 6.811936 53.139683
```

(until ID 518)

So what i want is a cmd program that takes two params (the coordinates) and then the program decides, by looking at the index, what Town and State it is from. How can i do that?
I already have the program read each line and stores the ID's and the values in two separate arrays.

So this is what i want the program looks like:

```
% java LeesKaart 6.665039 53.181004 < GemeentesNL.txt
```

output:

```
The coordinates x = 6.665039 and y = 53.181004 are located in: Town:    Leek, State: Groningen.
```

This is my code so far:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class LeesKaart {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        List<String> stringArray = new ArrayList<String>();
        List<Integer> intArray = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        while (StdIn.hasNextLine()) {
            String line = StdIn.readLine();
            String[] split = line.split(" ");
            intArray.add(Integer.parseInt(split[0]));
            stringArray.add(split[1]);
        }

        System.out.println(intArray);
        int x = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
        int y = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
        System.out.println("The coordinates x =" + x + " and y =" + y + " are located in (town), (state)"); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Dude, please use the spacebar to properly format your code.

Comment: @takendarkk you mean the cmd console? and do you have any ideas on the content of my question?

Comment: Nevermind, I did it for you. As for the content of the question - no. It is unclear what _exact_ problem you are having other than "I don't know how to do it".

Comment: @takendarkk yeah that is indeed the case. I dont know how you can "search" for the state and town if you enter the two coordinates

Comment: 1. `stringArray` is a bad name for something, which is NOT an array of strings. It is a bad name for anything, really. A proper name for a variable describes the variable. What about `coordinates`? `intArray` = the very same problem, what about `ìdList`?

2. Your coordinates are not integers. Why are you trying to parse them as if there were integers (`Integer.parseInt(args[0]);`)? You should handle them as `String` or `double`, anything else does not make sense.

Comment: It looks like you have accidentally created two accounts, this one and http://stackoverflow.com/users/3660293/user3660293 You can [contact the team](http://stackoverflow.com/contact) to have them merged, which will allow you to regain direct editing privileges on your contributions.

Comment: Possible dup of [Cmd redirection program](http://stackoverflow.com/q/33555896)